# Grouping and counting Users per Age category

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to split users in two categories, younger or older than 20, by looping thru them in order to calculate age value with Carbon.

```
    public function groupAndCountBasedOnAge($users) {
 // i'm giving the array keys & values
    $ageGroups = array('younger than 20' => 0,
                       'older than 20' => 0); 


foreach($users as $u) {

    $now = Carbon::now();
    $u->age = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $u->birth_date);
    $u->age = $now->diffInYears($u->age);  // getting actual age value for each user

    if($u->age < 20 ) {
        $ageGroups[younger than 20'] += 1;
    }
    elseif($u->age > 20 ) {
        $ageGroups['older than 20'] += 1;
    }

return $ageGroups;

}
```

}

```
public function index() {

$users = DB::table('users')->get();

$users = $this->groupAndCountBasedOnAge($users);

return view('/users/list', [
    'users' => $users
]);
```

}
    However dd($users) always returns the same array, no matter what I change:

```
array:2 [▼
  "less than 20" => 1
  "older than 20" => 0
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [partition()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-partition) and [Count()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-count) methods of [Laravel Collections](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections).

```
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

//

public function index() {

    $users = DB::table('users')->get();
    $users = $this->groupAndCountBasedOnAge($users);

    return view('/users/list', [
        'users' => $users
    ]);
}

public function groupAndCountBasedOnAge($users)
{
    list($under, $equalOrAbove) = collect($users)->partition(function ($user) {
        return Carbon::now()
            ->diffInYears(Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $user->birth_date)) < 20;
    });

    return [
        'underTwenty'  => [
            'users' => $under->all(),
            'count' => $under->count()
        ],
        'equalOrAboveTwenty' => [
            'users' => $equalOrAbove->all(),
            'count' => $equalOrAbove->count()
        ]
    ];
}
```

---

### Note

I've also grouped the users because I guessed you wanted this (acoording to name of your method).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    $age = Carbon::now()->diffInYears(Carbon::parse($u->birth_date));
```

Then:

```
    if ($age>20) 
    {
        $sol['greater']++
    }
    else
    {
        $sol['lesser']++
    }

    return $sol;
```